# Using Maven Release plug-in, update non-pom files

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin

I have a project in which I am using `maven-release-plugin` to make periodic releases. I also have some script files like `start.sh` and `stop.sh` which helps in starting up the project with multiple steps using just one command. The script contains commands like, (but not limited to)

```
java -jar module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My problem is, when I run release plugin it updates all the POM files but does nothing to this script file. I want to update these script files as well along with POM files. These script files contain the version number exactly the same as pom file and the way I mentioned.
Currently, I am updating these files manually after each release.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven release plugin is indeed all about releasing the maven version. Maven as a build tool, builds the artifact and releases it.

It has nothing to do with various script files. So you should decide first of all:

**Whether its a maven responsibility at all to deal with these scripts.**

If so, you can create your own plugin that will do the changes. Or alternatively you can use filtering feature, Maven build helper plugin to get the access to the versioning information and assembly plugin to prepare the distribution.

Otherwise, I see 2 possible options:

**Alternative 1**

Rename the versioned artifact with something generic that doesn't really include any maven related versioning information.

In this case the script will always be the same and will run: `java -jar my-module.jar`

**Alternative 2**

Complicate the script so that it will find the file and resolve the version dynamically. Then it will memorize the path to the file in some variable and will run `java -jar $here_is_the_resolved_file_with_version.jar`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I take #2 as a better option but I have to do some homework over it. As in #1, the problem is that I plan to go with docker soon, and when I want to clean up local images during shutdown of docker-compose the version of the image will cause an issue.

Comment: Also, I read(not tried) that I have to put the version of the jar in docker-compose and Dockerfile as well. Is there any different solution for that? Any suggestions.

Comment: Docker is a different story, less technical, but more "how do you see the process of versioning". You'll probably docker image per version, but you can also set a tag or many flags to the image: for example "latest" & "1.2.3" (version) So you can build orchestration so that it will always run "latest" tag of the image. However inside the image you'll still have to decide whether it worth to release the new maven jar or you'll prefer to rely on docker images versioning.

Comment: Since I am very new and have much less knowledge, I couldn't understand what you have mentioned.

Comment: oh, then I only can suggest to work step-by-step. Start with maven, and go with option 2 (script modification is easy to achieve). Then Learn docker and decide as you go...